# alter option automatically in search bar according to another option

Tags: python, html, django

I want that when we change the value of the state the value of the city also changes according to the values ​​in this state

search.html

```html
<div class="form-row">
           <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
             <label class="sr-only">State</label>
             <select name="city" class="form-control">
               <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">State</option>
               {% for key,value in state_choices.items %}
               <option name="state" value="{{ key }}">{{ value }}</option>
               {% endfor %}
             </select>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
             <label class="sr-only">City</label>
             <select name="city" class="form-control">
               <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Cité</option>
               {% if state.value == "Nabeul" %}
               {% for key,value in Nabeul_Choices.items %}
               <option name="city" value="{{ key }}">{{ value }}</option>
               {% endfor %}
               {% endif %}
             </select>
           </div>
         </div>
```

choices.py

```py
state_choices = {
   'Tunis':'Tunis',
   'Nabeul':'Nabeul',
}
tunis_choices = {
   'Tunis':'Tunis',
   'Le Bardo':'Le Bardo',
   'Le Kram':'Le Kram',
}
Nabeul_Choices = {
   'Nabeul':'Nabeul',
   'Hammamet':'Hammamet',
   'Dar Chaabane':'Dar Chaabane',
}
```

view.py

```py
def search(request):
   queryset_list = Listing.objects.order_by('-list_date').filter(is_published=True, type='Vendre')
   if 'state' in request.GET:
       state = request.GET['state']
       if state:
           queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(state__iexact=state)
   if 'city' in request.GET:
       city = request.GET['city']
       if city:
           queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(city__iexact=city)
context = {
       'Nabeul_Choices' : Nabeul_Choices,
       'tunis_choices' : tunis_choices,
       'state_choices' : state_choices,
}
   return render (request, 'listings/search.html', context)
```

the code works but when I change state the cities do not change automatically